# Why does Nginx only match the first location?

Tags: nginx

I'm struggling to understand something fundamental in Nginx.

I have the following config file:

```
server {
    listen      8080;
    server_name server.local;
    access_log  off;
    error_log   off;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';

    location = /v1/schema {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET';
        proxy_pass http://server.com:7777/v1/schema;
    }

    location = /v1/meta {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET';
        proxy_pass http://server.com:7777/v1/meta;
    }

}
```

In this case *only* /v1/schema works. And the other locations result in 404s. But if I swap /v1/schema and /v1/meta, only /v1/meta works.

Why is that?

### Update

Some more context.

I'm using the [Nginx Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) which settings are:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

The configuration mentioned above is what `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` points to.

Comment: What if you do nested locations with outer one being `location = /v1` and the inner ones `location = /v1/schema` and `location = /v1/meta`?

Comment: Unfortunately the same issue

Comment: Too bad. Have you tried it without the `=` (exact match)?

Comment: Or if that doesn't work either, maybe you can try the locations with a trailing `/`?

Comment: Yes I did. It seems to somehow pick up only the first `location` and never the second....

Comment: Can you show the entries in the access and error logs for the requests that are not working correctly?

Comment: Hi all, I've updated the question with some more context. Hope one of you is able to help, thanks 

Comment: Did you test your configuration files for errors? At least you are missing the root directive, but I don't think that matters.